# After login using passportjs how to access user details in React component

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, passport.js, passport-local

I am new to React

that's my login api in express

```
app.post("/login", function (req, res) {
  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  });    
req.login(user, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log("Error in login function");
      response.status(400).send({
        message: "Error in login function",
        result,
      });
    } else {
      res.redirect("http://localhost:3000")
    }
  });
});
```

and react part in which after login I redirected to this component but I want the username of logged in user.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Note from "./Note";
import AddNote from "./AddNote";
import axios from "axios";

function Keeper() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  function addNote(note) {
    setNotes((preValue) => {
      return [...preValue, note];
    });
  }

  function deleteNote(id) {
    setNotes((preValue) => {
      return preValue.filter((note, index) => {
        return index !== id;
      });
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = () => {
    const configuration = {
      method: "get",
      url: "http://localhost:5000/keeper",
      withCredentials: true
    }

    axios(configuration)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
  getUser();
  },[])
  return (
    <>
      <Header show={true} />
      <AddNote onAdd={addNote} />
      {notes.map((note, index) => {
        return (
          <Note
            key={index}
            id={index}
            title={note.title}
            content={note.content}
            onDel={deleteNote}
          />
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}

export default Keeper;
```

In a tutorial, I get to know that I have to make an API to access authenticated users but he does it using fetch but I wanted to do it using axios

```
app.get("/keeper", (req, res) => {
  if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.status(200).send({
      success: true,
      message: "success",
      user: req.user
    })
  }
});
```

the problem is, the req is null and I don't know what to send through axios from Keeper which is React component.
Please help me in this.

Comment: I just wanted to use passportjs to login in react if I am doing wrong in login or after login so kindly correct me with the correct way

Comment: So use axios, what is stopping you?

Comment: But how? in configuration what i have to write because when i do get req to the api I have to check the user is authenticated or not if authenticated i have to send the username but from where I get the user on YouTuber use fetch and he got the user in req itself but in axios what i have to send